# It is about finding probability. Situation is well explained.

Tags: probability

A monkey is sitting on $0$ on the real line in period $0$. In every period $t ∈ \left\{0, 1, 2, ...\right\}$, it moves $1$ to the right with probability $p$ and $1$ to the left with probability $1−p$, where $p ∈ [1/2, 1]$.

Let $\pi_k$ denote the probability that the monkey
will reach positive integer $k$ in some period $t > 0$. The
value of $\pi_k$ for any positive integer $k$ is?

My logic: I understand that the monkey can reach any integer $k$ on the real line in $k, k+2, k+4, ..$ time intervals with probabilities $p^k$, ${{k+2}\choose{k+1}}p^{k+1} (1-p). ....$ respectively. It is a complicated Binomial which I am unable to add. Can anyone suggest an easier method, or help me with this?

Comment: Intuitively, the probability of moving to the right is greater than the probability of moving to the left. So over many steps, the gradual flow of the monkey will be to the right. That is, the monkey should hit every positive integer eventually, no matter how big.

Comment: What if the probability of moving to the right was 1/2? Would the answer be 0 then?

Comment: No, it would not be 0 - in this case you'd expect an even number of jumps to the left and to the right, but it is in fact still expected that you will hit every state. I recall that it could be proven that this is some form of divergent case, where some quantity is infinite. Unfortunately I don't remember enough about this to come up with an answer. But I can tell you for certain that even with $p=1/2$, every state _is_ hit eventually. So the answer should always be $1$ with the range of $p$ given.

Comment: I learned this when I studied Gambler's ruin type problems (a form of a random walk which is a Markov process). You could look up some of these buzzwords for some inspiration perhaps (though they are quite broad topics)